# Interaction versus individual models logistic regression with constraint of the design

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, experiment-design

I have a data set that is the result of an experiment where customers were given two levels of a stimulus (discount incentive) high versus low. The experiment was set up whereby customers were put into a segment based on prior sales and then each customer per segment was randomly given a high discount and a low discount. The discount amounts (high and low) differed based on the segment.

Here is an example. So, if you are in segment 1, you were randomized to receive either 7.5% or 15% discount. If you were in segment 2 you received either 15% or 30% and so on.

Would this data be better analyzed for customer response with 8 separate logistic regressions or a single model with interactions between segment dummy codes and the numeric discount amount, even given that we know that we can not extrapolate between segments as someone in segment 1 really did not get the same offer as anyone in segment 2 (for example)?

The data is coded as having responded or not (purchased or did not) along with the amount of the purchase. The first concern is response. I want to understand how the discount amount effects purchase rate. I am interested in getting an estimate of response between the two points (we are satisfied that the effect is linear).

The significance of the segment is its a classification based on prior sales. The promotional offers were set up as "buy at least \$X and get \$Y off". The "\$X" differed by segment. If you were in segment 1 (relative to 2...8), you spent less historically and the hurdle amount to get the discount was less. Note, the offer was actually for example spend \$500 and get \$75 off (15%) for segment 2 low discount. I show it as a percentage. My fear is that the way the promotion was set up really makes the offers exclusive to each group and looking at this separately by segment might be the best way in this case.

[image]

**ANOTHER NOTE:**

To give more detail to my concern about not using separate models:
If I am in segment 2, that means I spent an amount lower than $500 historically and the offer I get was to spend at least \$500 and get \$75 off (15%). There are no examples in the data set where someone spent historically the same amount and was given an offer that said for example (spend at least \$750 and get \$100 off) which was the offer for segment #3 - low. This seems to violate having an interaction model.

Comment: What are the specific objectives of the analysis, such as null and alternative hypotheses?  That information might help you decide which approach is most suitable.  We can guess part of it--presumably you want to understand what effects the discounts might  have on some future action (and presumably you have coded those actions as a binary response variable)--but what role does the segmentation play?

Comment: @whuber I added some more detail. Appreciate the insight!

Comment: And added a bit more